# Lockscreen Widget Disable Screen Timeout

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen

I am making a calculator lockscreen widget for android, but the screen timeout is not reset during interactions with my widget so even while you are in the middle of using the calculator, the screen will timeout and turn off.  This is pretty annoying.

All the source is available on [github](https://github.com/bentglasstube/calc-widget).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to find out how to change the lockscreen timeout on Android 4.4 and it should be related.